# Power 12v Pump with two PSUs that may or may not both be on

Tags: power-supply, 12v, fluid-pump

Not an electrical engineer at all, however i will be in need of something like this. I have two systems that will share a liquid cooling system. They both run off of their own respective PSU's. I want the pump to run while they are both on or while only one of them is powered on. As far as I can tell all I would need to do is run the PSU's in parallel with diodes to prevent feedback. Would this work for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need two diodes.

You can get dual diodes in a single package, and perhaps consider getting Schottky diodes with very low forward voltage drop.

Depending on the current drawn by the pump perhaps something like the [MBR4060](http://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/MBR4060CT(-1)%20MBRB4060CT%20N0178%20REV.A.pdf) dual diode in a TO220 style case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwkk3X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If the supplies share a common ground, or one or both supplies are floating (not referenced to ground) you would only need the diodes in the positive leads.

If the negative sides of the supplies are at different voltages for some reason, you can't connect them this way.

To be safe in case the supplies are, or may be, at different potentials, you would need a relay, wired like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz1CgQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If V1 is on, the relay will be pulled in, and the pump will be powered from V1, regardless of the state of V2.

If V1 is off, the relay will be released, and the pump will be powered by V2, if it is on.